# How can I write HTML code only if JS is enabled?

Tags: javascript, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a html opposite to noscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript)

`<noscript>` makes it easy to have HTML code as a fallback if JS is disabled... but what if I want to have HTML code which is only shown when scripts are *enabled*? I can have a JS block which dynamically writes HTML, but is there a nicer way to do it using some regular HTML?

let's say I have a link:

```
<a href="test.com">This should only appear if Javascript is enabed</a>
```

Comment: duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript

Answer (score 12):

Use a HTML element with `style="display:none"`, set that to `display:block` from JavaScript.

Sample code (ugly as hell, but just to give you the idea)

```
<div id="hideThisFromNonJs" style="display:none">
Bla bla bla
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('hideThisFromNonJs').style.display='block';
</script>
```

Comment: In general I'm against [mixing CSS in your HTML](http://phrogz.net/CSS/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#separatestyle). I can't decide if this is appropriate in this case or not, though.

Comment: @Phrogz Very valid remark. How about `<div class="hidden">` with the `hidden` class defined as `display:none` in an external style sheet. The JS would just remove the class.

Comment: Yup, that'd be good, and more general than your or my current (simpler to implement) answers involving ID only. I do find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript/431554#431554) interesting, though.

Answer (score 3):

> I can have a JS block which dynamically writes HTML, but is there a nicer way to do it using some regular HTML?

Unfortunately, no, there isn't. You have to use some form of JavaScript.

I guess you could set up a class or something that is hidden by CSS:

```
<span class="jsonly">etc</span>
```

And then you could run something like:

```
$('.jsonly').show();
```

Comment: @Pointy The reason I quoted was because I was specifically talking about "using some regular HTML" - I've expanded the answer to avoid confusion

Comment: OK, well now that you've modified the answer, it looks like what everybody else is saying :-) - I didn't downvote but now I'll upvote

Comment: I'll downvote because this is jQuery, not Javascript. If edited to be Javascript, it would be identical to other answers.

Answer (score 3):

```
<style type="text/css" media="all">
  #test { display:none }
</style>
...
<a id="test" href="test.com">...</a>
...
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'inline'; // or 'block', or whatever.
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

We appoached this by giving the elements a css class that styles them as `display:none` and showing it with JS.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but if you give the element a style, say "hasjs"

```
.hasjs{
    display: none;
}
```

Then remove this with some jQuery.

```
$('.hasjs').removeClass('hasjs');
```