# All important site Prestashop content must be made available to search robots with js turned off and given in plain html

Tags: javascript, html, content-management-system, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

Problem:
All important site content must be made available to search robots with js turned off and given in plain html

Example:
Here is the page with js enabled - http://joxi.ru/D2PEk8RSpepVxA
But the same page with off - http://joxi.ru/a2XDgOyU1z1Gq2 (And this is bad)

All important and user-friendly content and links should be provided to search engines in the form of simple HTML code so that they can efficiently crawl, index, and rank pages.
What advise, what solutions offer?
Thank!

Answer (score 0):

Common solution is to add special class to body, `js-disabled` which should be changed to `js-enabled` using... js :) this way you can target elements using CSS on site without js being enabled and force them to display in some way

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181346/how-can-i-write-html-code-only-if-js-is-enabled

Comment: How to implement on Prestashop?

Comment: Well, add `js-disabled` class to your `body` tag and change it to `js-enabled` using... JS :) In PrestaShop 1.7 you can do that by editing `themes/yourtheme/layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl` and putting .js in `themes/yourtheme/assets/js/custom.js`

Comment: themes/yourtheme/layouts/layout-both-columns.tpl
<div id="body_wrapper" style="display:none">
.......
</div>

themes/yourtheme/assets/js/custom.js
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('body_wrapper').style.display='block';
</script>
Ok?

Comment: no it's not ok... why are you hidding a div instead of manipulating classes?