# Displaying a form only if Javascript is enabled

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a form which uses JS to do some things when the user clicks the submit button. I want to disable the form and hide it if the user does not have JS enabled. I thought I could do it like so:

```
<form style="display:none;" onLoad="this.style.display='inline'">
    Text
    <input type="text">
</form>
<noscript>Noscript stuff here</noscript>
```

However, it doesn't work. Since I don't really use JS, I'm probably just making an embarrassingly obvious mistake, and I'm going to take a guess and say that it has something to do with the "this" part.

Comment: A form doesn't have an "onload" event, which is why the posted code won't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I write HTML code only if JS is enabled?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181346/how-can-i-write-html-code-only-if-js-is-enabled) which is actualy a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try an invisible div that gets shown via JavaScript when the page loads:

```
<div id="hideThisFromNonJs" style="display:none">
    <form>
       Text
       <input type="text">
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
     document.getElementById('hideThisFromNonJs').style.display='block';
</script>
```

Comment: Looks like we referenced the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181346/how-can-i-write-html-code-only-if-js-is-enabled haha

Comment: Hahahaha what are the odds! :)

Comment: haha pretty good considering it's the top Google result!

Answer (score 4):

What you can do is have the form hidden by default, and then use javascript to unhide it. Something like this should work:

```
<form id="jsform" style="display:none;">
    Text
    <input type="text">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('jsform').style.display='block';
</script>
```

Comment: @user2864740 Thanks, I forgot to edit OP's markup

Comment: Cheers. I'd accept the answer, but for some reason it's telling me I have to wait 7 minutes. Guess I'll come back then.

Comment: @Hiigaran yeah, they make you wait a little bit to make sure enough good answers roll in... You should accept chridam's answer though, he has the same thing as me, but answered first...

Comment: Sure thing. They're currently both showing the same minutes ago, so I had to pick one at random.