# Is using partial HTML comment in noscript to hide content when javascript is disable, guarantee to work everywhere?

Tags: html, noscript, lynx

I want my website to work on text-based browsers like lynx

There's some part of the HTML that are useless in it like the profile photo

I tried the most upvoted solution put here [Is there a HTML opposite to <noscript>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30319/is-there-a-html-opposite-to-noscript?rq=1)

which is

```
<head>
    <noscript><style> .jsonly { display: none } </style></noscript>
</head>
```

However Lynx does not hide it

What I found to work is doing this

```
<body>
    <noscript> <!--  </noscript>
         <img src="foobar.png">
    <noscript> -->  </noscript>
</body>
```

This works and it seems to work on all browsers I have tested, i.e the image is hidden when javascript is disabled, and shown otherwise.

However I would like to know if it is a documented behaviour in HTML5 parser or if it's just an edge case that everybody has implemented the same way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's guaranteed to work in every User Agent that does respect the [HTML parsing](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html) rules, yes.

If you're ready to dive into this wonderful machinery...

Assuming the [scripting flag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#scripting-flag) is enabled, and we already processed the `<body>` tag.

- The parser is in the ["in body" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody), and the tokenizer in the [data state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state).
- The `<noscript>` tag is emitted [[text-fragment link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody:%7E:text=%22noembed%22-,A%20start%20tag%20whose%20tag%20name%20is%20%22noscript%22)],
- We enter the [generic raw text parsing algorithm](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#generic-raw-text-element-parsing-algorithm).
- From there we switch the tokenizer to the [RAWTEXT state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#rawtext-state) and go
  to the ["text"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-incdata) insertion mode.
- The tokenizer sees the character `<` and switches to the [RAWTEXT less-than sign state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#rawtext-less-than-sign-state).
- It finds a `!` character and goes back to the [RAWTEXT state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#rawtext-state) while emitting this character to the parser which just [inserts](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#insert-a-character) it.
- It continues processing the input the same way until it finds the next `<` character.
- This time it's followed by the `/` character and thus enters the [RAWTEXT end tag open state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#rawtext-end-tag-open-state).
- Then the next sequence is ASCII alpha, it goes to the [RAWTEXT end tag name state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#rawtext-end-tag-name-state).
- It consumes all of `noscript` and finds the `>` character.
- Our current end tag (`</noscript>`) is an [appropriate end tag token](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#appropriate-end-tag-token).
- The tokenizer switches back to the [data state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state) and emits the current end tag.
- The parser (still in the ["text"](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-incdata) insertion mode) [[text-fragment link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody:%7E:text=%22noembed%22-,A%20start%20tag%20whose%20tag%20name%20is%20%22noscript%22)] goes past the current node and switches back to the "in body" insertion mode.
- From there it will treat the rest normally, producing an `<img>` self-closing tag with all its attributes, until it meets the next `<noscript>` tag, and pushes the `-->` sequence in it as text.

If the [scripting flag](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#scripting-flag) was disabled though,

- When the first `<noscript>` tag is met, we just insert an [ordinary](https://ordinary) element out of it.
- We are still in the ["in body" insertion mode](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inbody) and the tokenizer is still in the [data state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#data-state).
- The `<` character leads the tokenizer to the [tag open state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#tag-open-state).
- The `!` one, to the [markup declaration state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#markup-declaration-open-state).
- And the next two `--`, to the [comment state](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#comment-state).
- From there everything until the next `-->` sequence will be part of the comment token that will get emitted to the parser and thus treated as text.
- The parser [inserts the comment](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#insert-a-comment)
- It then gets the closing `</noscript>` token and inserts the current node, with the comment inside.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailled and documented answers  , so  will keep using that trick to make my browsers lynx compatible ^^'